# React: migrating from tree structure to MobX

Tags: reactjs, axios, mobx, mobx-react

My application has grown to a degree where there's dependability between grandchildren of the same parents to a level where it's becoming a mess - I need state management, and MobX is the choice due to the relative low complexity of the application and team size(it's just me). Redux seems overkill.

I'm trying to learn MobX but a bit confused about how to integrate it with, say, Ajax calls. I'm using Axios to fetch data from a REST API.

My current component structure is hierarchical as such:

```
            <Container /> // Dummy component
     <Child 1 />     <Child 2 /> // Ajax calls exist in both
<Grandchild 1.1 /> <Grandchild 1.1 /> // There are ~10 for each
```

I make `axios` get requests in both Child 1 and Child 2, calling it in `componentDidMount`, and propagate the data down to the children with the one-way data flow, like one normally would in React.

Let's say my `<Child 1/>` component looks something like this now:

```
class Child1 extends React.Component {
    // Set initial state etc.
    loadData = () => {
        let that = this;
        axios.get("/api/child1/").then(function(response){
            that.setState({data: response.data });
        }).catch(function(error){
            // Handles error
            })
    };

    componentDidMount () {   
        this.loadData();
    }
// Continues .. 
}
```

Where in the structure should this `axios.get` be now that I switch to MobX, and how do I access it from `Child1`?

Assuming I have different `axios.get` calls, should they all live inside a single `store.js` file and be invoked by `this.props`?

Comment: mobx is just a library that makes you data reactive: your view will get updated when data change. You can still put data wherever you want.

Comment: That I understand. So far I see no benefit except having to import a bunch of utility tools to make the behavior as if you just did the ajax calls inside your React component. It just makes simple things complicated, when it says it's supposed to do the opposite?

Comment: And it makes `this.props` to child components behave extremely strange..

Comment: You can wrap all ajax calls into several services if you like and then use dependence injection to retrieve them. Usually I have multiple (nested) container components consisting of other components and their common data without any logic code.

Comment: @Zen that sounds interesting... If you dont mind could you fiddle up an example of the Store, and then how you'd invoke the ajax calls in the react class and pass the data? pseudo-ish is fine